# Set firefox developer edition as the default browser in VS Code on Linux

Tags: firefox, browser, mx-linux, visual-studio-code

I have installed firefox developer edition on my MX-Linux. When I tried to configure the live server of VS Code to run it as default, I failed. I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319065/how-do-i-set-up-vs-code-live-server-extension-to-use-firefox-developer-on-linux/63324063#63324063) to set up, but ultimately it is not working for me.

What I did after following the above mentioned link is to include this piece of line in the settings.json file after I entered config live server in the search bar `"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "/usr/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop"`. However, it is not working out for me.

Did I miss anything out here? I know I could add a comment on that thread, but I don't have enough reputations on stackoverflow to comment anything. So I had to post here.

I hope anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was missing. I added the path to the desktop entry of the firefox developer edition. Instead, what should have been done was to add the path of the actual application location. In my case, the path of the application was this `/opt/firefox-dev/firefox`(I saved the firefox developer edition in this directory).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this technique on my window 11 laptop ✅✅✅
first Install Firefox developer edition / Firefox nightly and open one tab of Firefox developer edition browser & then go to vs code settings.json file (ctrl+shift+p) & then change the line.

```
 "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "firefox",
```

after doing these steps your problem is solved..

Comment: On Linux-based OSs, you need to add the path to the command that will be used to run Firefox browser; simply writing "firefox" will not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).